# Process Builder in Salesforce

Tags: process-builder

I am Learning the Process Builder Feature in Salesforce which is very to easy to manipulate any type of records.

In the Immediate Action **Submit for Approval** using Process Builder, I know the Usage and I know how to do the **Specific Approval Process** option. But i don't know the particular usage of **Default Approval Process**.

How that option could be used in process builder?
Can anyone please give an example on How to use that **Default Approval Process** option in Process Builder.

Thanks in advance.